# Error while using Highcharts in angularjs using requirejs. Custom directive throwing errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive, requirejs

I am trying to include highcharts in my PWA application built with angularjs 1.3.15
I have declared highcharts in my bower.json

My app config(contains require config) looks like :

`require.config({
    paths: {
        "angular": "lib/angular/angular.min",
        "Q": "lib/q/q",
        ..
        "angular-my-highcharts": "lib/mydirectives/src/my.highcharts/my.highcharts"
        "highcharts": "lib/highcharts/highcharts"
    }
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'highcharts': {
            exports: 'highcharts'
        }
       'angular-my-highcharts': {
            deps: ['highcharts']
        }
    });`

I am trying to create a custom directive for highcharts. I am using sample code that can be found in this blog https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js/.

```
var highchartsModule = angular.module('my.highcharts', []);
highchartsModule.controller('HighchartsController', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
    $scope.chartOptions = {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    };
}]);

highchartsModule.directive('hcChart', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
        options: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        Highcharts.chart(element[0], scope.options);
    }
};
});
```

I have included my.highcharts module in my app.js

```
 app = angular.module('MYAPP', ["ngRoute","my.weekselector" ....... "my.highcharts"])
```

and finally I have put the following in my html

```
 <div>
    <hc-chart options="chartOptions">Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>
 </div>
```

But I am getting this error while running the application

```
angular.min.js?_sw-precache=ca1a58818682c3e858a9beb:102 

ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
at link (http://localhost/js/lib/my-directives/src/my.highcharts/my.highcharts.js:28:13)
```

Comment: Could you prepare a simplified online demo of your app/chart with sample data (codesandbox, jsfiddle)?

Comment: Can you see `lib/highcharts/highcharts` in the network panel in the dev tools?